# How do I store a list of files into a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file which will parse through a given directory and get me all XML files.

These XML file names are to be stored in a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the `FOR` command. Read the usage information first, try `HELP FOR`. Then, experiment with this examples:

```
FOR %%a in (*.xml) DO ECHO %%a >>xmllist.txt
```

or

```
FOR /R %%a in (*.xml) DO ECHO %%a >>xmllist.txt
```

or

```
FOR /R %%a in (*.xml) DO ECHO %%~na >>xmllist.txt
```

and choose what fits better with your requirements

Answer (score 1):

```
dir /b *.xml > xmlfiles.txt
```

Comment: Say my directory is at C:\www\ folder 

where do i specify the directory 

and also the xml files will be in sub folders too

Comment: dir /b *.xml > xmlfiles.txt

this gives me the file name along with the path but i dont need the path to be stored only the file name

Comment: Try `dir /?`. It'll tell you all you need to know.